# Bootstrap positioning not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Just currently working on my site and using bootstrap to help me as i was told it was a great framework to use. Anyway i am currently having a problem putting text in the header and positioning it in the right place.

My html code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">  
  <div class="container">     
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class = "Text">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <h1>Text1</h1>
        <h2>Text2</h2>
        <h3>Joruney</h3>
        <p>Starting to work around here</p>
      </a>  
     </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">  
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Text<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
                <li><a href="#">Text1</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Text2</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Text3</a></li>   
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #760003;
    padding: 30px;
}
.Text h1 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 59px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.Text h2 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    float: left;
}

.Text h3 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 44px;
    margin-top: -17px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    float: left;
}

.Text p{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    float: left;
}
```

So i am trying to ahive by getting it to look like:

```
    Text1 Text2 Text 3
Starting to work around here
```

However what its actually looking like is:

```
Text1 Text2 Text3 
                   Starting to work around here
```

I cant get the p tag to move under it. Now i tried to use  `position: absolute;` however when i resize the page its not mobile friendly at all. It looks awful but i can get it in the right place.

Could anyone help me with this problem so that i can get the text to go under the three text headers and when it resizes it will all stay in that same block and never move but just get smaller?

Thanks for all the help

To give an example of what i was trying to get

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijoLQ.jpg)

U an see Text 1 Text 2 and Text3 are there 
and then the p tag is below.

Comment: can you place your code in a snippet? it will be easier to assist you...

Comment: I have re edited and put the whole html code in there to make it easy, i wanted to try and make it smaller but i think its getting people confused

Comment: wait is this for a navbar?

Comment: Do which part are you stuck with and you haven't explained?

Comment: Sorry its the text bit. Its the header bar. I am trying to put the text in it and arrange it as i showed above

Comment: Sorry i will try and explain better. I have made the header and the nav bar in it. The nav bar is fine. On the left hand side i want there to be the text and shown above and i want to style it that way . Were i have text1 text2 and 3 all on the same link and then below it have the p tag

Comment: I put an image as an example if people are trying to understand wat i am going for

Comment: why so many negative margins? why `.Text h2 {margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    margin-top: -22px;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have created what you have asked for, you should look at the CSS properties `text-align` and `display`

I have created a `ul` with three `li`

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">  
  <div class="container">     
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class = "Text">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <ul>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <h6>This is below</h6>
      </a>  
     </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">  
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Text<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
                <li><a href="#">Text1</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Text2</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Text3</a></li>   
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #760003;
    padding: 20px;
}
.Text ul {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.Text ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.Text h6 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This was done very fast to give you an idea of how to do it, you should look at the Bootstrap Documentation and learn about the CSS positioning

https://getbootstrap.com/components

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Comment: Fantastic thank you very much for the help, and i will defo do that x

Comment: @Nevershow2016 try not to capitalize your class names though as that's bad practice ;)